# How do I make two or more lines of Lore on an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am playing Minecraft and am making a map for a contest. I want some lore but cannot figure out how to do two or more lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's see...

`/give @p 268 1 0 {display:{Lore:[Hey look at this awesome lore!]}}`

This would give you a wooden sword with a single line of lore. But putting a comma in there:

`/give @p 268 1 0 {display:{Lore:[Hey look at this, awesome lore!]}}`

Would separate it into two lines. Simple enough answer, can't find much to elaborate on - except it works just like other data tags, where a comma indicates another value (like:
`/give @p 268 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:100},{id:0,lvl:1}]}`
separates the id and lvl values, and the separate bundles)

Comment: Also note: if you want to have a comma in your lore text, you need to put it in quotes. Example: `{display:{Lore:["Hello, World!", "Check out my lore text!"]}}` would produce 2 lines

Comment: @Unionhawk I forgot about that. :P

Answer (score 2):

What is the item?
So here is an nbt data of a multiline lore.
2023

```
Display:{Lore:['{"text":"lore1"}','{"text":"lore2"}']}
```

display:

```
Item (#0000)
lore1
lore2
```

## Using Multiline Lore With item

Here is an example with a wooden sword:

```
/give @p wooden_sword{Display:{Lore:['{"text":"lore1"}','{"text":"lore2"}']}} 1
```

display:

```
wooden sword
lore1
lore2

attack damage: 4
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want more lore then what you can fit in chat, use a command block, they can fit a lot more text then the chat bar can, something crazy like 1,300 characters or something

Answer (score -2):

I think it is the Pipe symbol <kbd>|</kbd>.

On most keyboards it is above the backslash <kbd>\</kbd>)

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what it is? There is not enough detail to make it easy enough to understand.

Comment: It's called a pipe... goodness.